Moodle: Cannot open modal to enroll user into a training
Cannot enroll user(s) through enroll button on course.
Some info:

Moodle 4.5 (But I have has the same problem on 4.3)
Site administration > Development > Debugging : Development mode = on
1 addtional plugin installed: Attendance plugin
localhost: no problems there
staging server: this is where the error persists

A bit of context
Hi, I am currently working on a moodle platform, where I have a local instance, a staging instance and a production instance. Currently I am customizing it to our needs step by step but I haven't really touched the core code base of moodle itself. Most of my work was on a moodle plugin (Attendance plugin by Dan Marsden).
Locally everything seems to work just fine so I thought, time to put it on my staging to check for any surprises! I update the staging server, create a test account so my admin account can enroll it in a course (course > participants). but when click on the "enroll users" button, I get the following error:
SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 53907 (line 1 column 53908)
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at https://staging.adress/lib/javascript.php/1733494483/lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:77349
    at l (https://staging.adress/lib/javascript.php/1733494483/lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:77466)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://staging.adress/lib/javascript.php/1733494483/lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:80265)

In my inspector console, I get the same error, prefixed by jQuery.Deferred exception:
I also looked at the response in my header, it's a little long, but essentially it contains the data to build the html I think:
[{
   "error":false,
   "data":{
      "html": "\n<form autocomplete=\"off\" action=\"https:\/\/Staging.server\/lib\/ajax\/service.php\" method=\"post\" accept-char..."
      "javascript":"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""https"://staging.server/fWcr7ZYpfCrhN3TeHIqxuik_PP8xlKQoOL0IylUV8lxscsxSQ-GxjKW_u30skc3dxwEPoGBS-hgIy5Xsg6nY_g=="></script><script>\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nM.util.js_pending(\"core\/first\");require(['core\/first'], function() {\n;\nM.util.js_pending('core_form\/showadvanced'); require(['core_form\/showadvanced'], function(amd) {amd.init(\"mform1_Ksx3pJmfCs0llG3\"); M.util.js_complete('core_form\/showadvanced');});;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_userlist\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['core\/form-autocomplete'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"#id_userlist\",\n                   0,\n                   \"enrol_manual\\\/form-potential-user-selector\",\n                   \"Search\",\n                   0,\n                   1,\n                   \"No selection\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_cohortlist\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['core\/form-autocomplete'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"#id_cohortlist\",\n                   0,\n                   \"core\\\/form-cohort-selector\",\n                   \"Search\",\n                   0,\n                   1,\n                   \"No selection\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_roletoassign\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_recovergrades\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_startdate\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_duration\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_enabled\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_day\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_month\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_year\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_hour\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend_minute\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['theme_boost\/form-display-errors'], function(module) {\n    module.enhance(\"id_timeend\");\n});\n;\n\nrequire(['jquery'], function($) {\n    $('#id_timeend_label').css('cursor', 'default');\n    $('#id_timeend_label').click(function() {\n        $('#id_timeend')\n            .find('button, a, input:not([type=\"hidden\"]), select, textarea, [tabindex]')\n            .filter(':not([disabled]):not([tabindex=\"0\"]):not([tabindex=\"-1\"])')\n            .first().focus();\n    });\n});\n\n});M.util.js_complete(\"core\/first\");\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script>\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nM.yui.add_module({\"mform\":{\"name\":\"mform\",\"fullpath\":\"https:\\\/\\\/staging.server\\\/lib\\\/javascript.php\\\/1733494483\\\/lib\\\/form\\\/form.js\",\"requires\":[\"base\",\"node\"]}});\n\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script>\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nrequire([\"jquery\"], function($) {\n                M.str = $.extend(true, M.str, {\"moodle\":{\"lastmodified\":\"Last modified\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"error\":\"Error\",\"info\":\"Information\",\"yes\":\"Yes\",\"no\":\"No\"},\"repository\":{\"type\":\"Type\",\"size\":\"Size\",\"invalidjson\":\"Invalid JSON string\",\"nofilesattached\":\"No files attached\",\"filepicker\":\"File picker\",\"logout\":\"Logout\",\"nofilesavailable\":\"No files available\",\"norepositoriesavailable\":\"Sorry, none of your current repositories can return files in the required format.\",\"fileexistsdialogheader\":\"File exists\",\"fileexistsdialog_editor\":\"A file with that name has already been attached to the text you are editing.\",\"fileexistsdialog_filemanager\":\"A file with that name has already been attached\",\"renameto\":\"Rename to \\\"{$a}\\\"\",\"referencesexist\":\"There are {$a} links to this file\",\"select\":\"Select\"},\"admin\":{\"confirmdeletecomments\":\"Are you sure you want to delete the selected comment(s)?\"}});\n            });\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script>\n\/\/<![CDATA[\n(function() {Y.use(\"moodle-form-dateselector\",function() {M.form.dateselector.init_date_selectors({\"firstdayofweek\":1,\"mon\":\"Mon\",\"tue\":\"Tue\",\"wed\":\"Wed\",\"thu\":\"Thu\",\"fri\":\"Fri\",\"sat\":\"Sat\",\"sun\":\"Sun\",\"january\":\"January\",\"february\":\"February\",\"march\":\"March\",\"april\":\"April\",\"may\":\"May\",\"june\":\"June\",\"july\":\"July\",\"august\":\"August\",\"september\":\"September\",\"october\":\"October\",\"november\":\"November\",\"december\":\"December\"});\n});\n M.util.js_pending('random6757fb95a62d77'); Y.on('domready', function() {  M.util.js_pending('random6757fb95a62d77'); Y.use('mform', function(Y) { M.form.initFormDependencies(Y, \"mform1_Ksx3pJmfCs0llG3\", {\"timeend[enabled]\":{\"checked\":{\"1\":[[\"duration\"]]},\"notchecked\":{\"1\":[[\"timeend[day]\",\"timeend[month]\",\"timeend[year]\",\"timeend[hour]\",\"timeend[minute]\",\"timeend[calendar]\"]]}}});  M.util.js_complete('random6757fb95a62d77'); });  M.util.js_complete('random6757fb95a62d77'); });\n})();\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n"
   }
}]


I have found similar questions on stackoverflow or the moodle forums, but those were all talking about custom JQuery code, I have not changed any JQuery in the core moodle code since installing a clean 4.5 version.
Is it because I have customized code (including removing a jquery code to replace it by a javascript file) in a plugin that is not related to the page in question?
Let me know if I am missing some information in my post.

Can you show the relevant part of that JSON, please, instead of just the start?

Sounds like the JSON is malformed. How do you build it?

@C3roe I updated the response json to include all the javascript in the response. I quickly ran it through a fromatter and it seems that the html part is not having any issues, so I left that partially out.

@NicoHaase I did not build this myself, this page is part of the moodle template code on installation. which is why I'm confused by the error as it worked before, then suddenly not so much anymore. while not having updated any core/template code

"javascript":"<script type=""text/javascript"" - looks like those double double quotes are invalidating the JSON. But why those are duplicated, instead of escaped with a backslash, like inside the html property value, I couldn't tell you.
